# Pi 3 loses network connection

Tags: pi-3, networking, connection

I'm having a strange problem.

Every few days my Pi loses the connection to my WiFi and only after I disconnect and connect the Pi to the power supply does the connection come back.

I saw in the `/var/log/messages` the lines:

```
Jun 11 11:18:06 MY_PI kernel: [    2.385881] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, e2:18:25:ad:b4:4a
Jun 11 11:18:06 MY_PI kernel: [    3.381314] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Jun 11 11:18:06 MY_PI kernel: [    3.801944] NET: Registered protocol family 10
Jun 11 11:18:06 MY_PI kernel: [    4.496800] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
Jun 11 11:18:06 MY_PI kernel: [    5.100023] gpiomem-bcm2835 3f200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0x3f200000
Jun 11 11:18:06 MY_PI kernel: [    5.131787] bcm2835-wdt 3f100000.watchdog: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
Jun 11 11:18:06 MY_PI kernel: [    5.352605] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
Jun 11 11:18:06 MY_PI kernel: [    5.379316] brcmfmac_sdio mmc1:0001:1: firmware: direct-loading firmware brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin
Jun 11 11:18:06 MY_PI kernel: [    5.382946] brcmfmac_sdio mmc1:0001:1: firmware: direct-loading firmware brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.txt
Jun 11 11:18:06 MY_PI kernel: [    5.467877] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
Jun 11 11:18:06 MY_PI kernel: [    6.244507] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
Jun 11 11:18:06 MY_PI kernel: [    6.246223] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Jun 11 11:18:06 MY_PI kernel: [   67.775004] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Jun 11 11:18:06 MY_PI kernel: [   67.776660] brcmfmac: power management disabled
Jun 11 11:18:09 MY_PI rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Sun Jun 11 11:18:39 2017 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jun 11 11:18:09 MY_PI kernel: [   72.940734] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Jun 11 11:18:09 MY_PI wpa_action: WPA_IFACE=wlan0 WPA_ACTION=CONNECTED
Jun 11 11:18:09 MY_PI wpa_action: WPA_ID=0 WPA_ID_STR= WPA_CTRL_DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
Jun 11 11:18:09 MY_PI wpa_action: ifup wlan0=default
Jun 11 11:18:14 MY_PI wpa_action: creating sendsigs omission pidfile: /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid
Jun 11 11:18:14 MY_PI wpa_action: bssid=f4:c2:6d:7f:4d:ff
Jun 11 11:18:14 MY_PI wpa_action: freq=2437
Jun 11 11:18:14 MY_PI wpa_action: ssid=MY_WIFI
Jun 11 11:18:14 MY_PI wpa_action: id=0
Jun 11 11:18:14 MY_PI wpa_action: mode=station
Jun 11 11:18:14 MY_PI wpa_action: pairwise_cipher=CCMP
Jun 11 11:18:14 MY_PI wpa_action: group_cipher=CCMP
Jun 11 11:18:14 MY_PI wpa_action: key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
Jun 11 11:18:14 MY_PI wpa_action: wpa_state=COMPLETED
Jun 11 11:18:14 MY_PI wpa_action: ip_address=192.168.1.2
Jun 11 11:18:14 MY_PI wpa_action: p2p_device_address=b8:cc:ed:d0:c3:aa
Jun 11 11:18:14 MY_PI wpa_action: address=b8:cc:ed:d0:c3:aa
Jun 11 11:18:14 MY_PI wpa_action: uuid=58dedc32-65e0-5eb3-ae75-c0bed55ca4a1
```

Does anyone has an idea why this is happening?

(I do not think it's a power supply problem).

Comment: How have you ruled out power? Power issues are the most common cause of intermittent failures like this.

Comment: I am using  5V-3A 3000mA Power Adapter Supply...

Comment: That is what the label says, but not neccesarily what the board sees.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for specific power supply?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that wireless power management kicks in.

Try the following crontab entry (`sudo crontab -e`).

`@reboot              (sleep 30; /sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off)&`

Comment: I have tried it, and still, it happen again now...

Comment: That's unfortunate.  I'm afraid I have nothing else to suggest.